# Liferay variable $user vs $realuser

Tags: java, liferay, velocity

There are number of variables available in liferay for custom TPL files.I have found that on below link of liferay.

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/variables-available-to-layout-a-template-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-09-en

But I have confusion on below variables.I am not able understand differrent between $user and $realuser.

can anybody help on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have proper permissions, you can "impersonate" other users. Try it: Log in as administrators, go to the user management screen and the "Action" button will have an "impersonate" option. With this active, the permission checks will be done for `${user}`, even though you gave the permissions of `${realuser}` when you logged in (realuser would be your admin account).

The dockbar will also show you both user names (aka "you are impersonating... be yourself again" - with a link to stop impersonating)

Answer (score 2):

While impersonating another user acount:

user -> user has been supplanted (regular).

realuser -> user that has impersonated the other one (Administrator)